# Select and count rows by category

Tags: database

I've try to make some code, but I found some problem...

This is my tables....

category table

```
+---------------------------+-----------------------+
+ id_category               +  name                 +
+---------------------------+-----------------------+
+   1                       +  Adidas               +
+   2                       +  Logo                 +
+   3                       +  Levis                +
+---------------------------+-----------------------+
```

item table :

```
+---------+-----------------+-----------------------+
+ id_item +  id_category    +  name                 +
+---------+-----------------+-----------------------+
+   1     +      1          +  T-Shirt003           +
+   2     +      2          +  LogoShoes            +
+   3     +      3          +  Panty003             +
+---------------------------+-----------------------+
```

and I want to make a result like this :

```
No.   Category         Total Item
1.     Adidas              1
2.     Logo                1
3.     Levis               1
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: uhummm... Google sql syntax

Comment: You have already identified you need a `count`. Take a look at the `JOIN` as well.

Comment: yes, i was search on google, but still got the answers... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `GROUP BY` option

```
SELECT
    COUNT(item_table.id_category) as total,
    category_table.name
FROM
    category_table
    INNER JOIN item_table ON item_table.id_category = category_table.id_category
GROUP BY
    id_category
```

Comment: thanks, its work for me..but, the result only show when the category have an item.. can it show even if the category is NULL?

Comment: Great @pitokeraf. Accept the answer if your happy :-)

Comment: You'd probably have to use a LEFT JOIN